# PhP get content of all files in directory

Tags: php

I have many files in a directory that look similar to:

```
personalchat.spud.3353.1789
personalchat.guest.3355.1789
personalchat.ken.3355.1789
```

each file essentially has a few lines of html inside, and wanting to open all files, pull the content to the screen. I can do it by hardcoding a single filename but not all at once or by using a * for filename

Code:

```
$names=file('/var/www/html/web/www/chat.support/status/personalchat*');

foreach($names as $name)
{
   echo $name.'<br>';
}
```

##UPATE 2

I tried changing to an array but it only displays the name of the files not the content of each:

I am able to list the files as an array:

```
personalchat.mick.3350.1733
personalchat.guest.3352.1739
personalchat.test.3351.1736
```

But not able to display the name of each file but not the content:

```
$mydir = '/var/www/html/web/www/chat.support/status/';
$myfiles = array_diff(scandir($mydir), array('.', '..'));

foreach($myfiles as $name)
{
   echo $name.'<br>';
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

file() function reads 1 file. So you need an array of files to read with file().

May be you can try to create such array using scandir() first, and then read the file 1 by one.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated code above with a suggestion, any idea how I can get it to modify my code to get it to display the content of each array rather than just the file name?

Comment: In such case, I mean, a unknown array, the best is to get it displayed in the php-log or the output to understand the array's structure.
typically, try error_log(var_export($your_array, true));==>to php-log, or just var_export($your_array); ==>default output.

scandir() details can be found here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php